# FileZilla not working on Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, ftp, windows-server-2008, filezilla

I'm battling to get FileZilla working on Server 2008 R2. Until this morning, I had one 2008 and one XP machine, and always just used the XP one for FTP. I now have two 2008 machines and no FTP client. I'v tried the Network Wizard in FileFilla, and I have also tried switching off Windows Firewall, with no joy. It's worth mentioning that my XP machine was using the same modem/router, for an ADSL connection with dynamic external IP, and it was working.

The last few log entries on my last attempt are as follows:

```
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   230 Logged on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PORT 196,210,184,52,255,146
Response:   200 Port command successful
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening data channel for directory list.
Response:   425 Can't open data connection.
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking about FileZilla Server or FileZilla Client on 2008 R2?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can absolutely verify that FileZilla works with Windows Server 2008 R2 (used it many times myself). So, it's probably a configuration problem.

Sounds obvious, but have you tried switching between PASSIVE and ACTIVE mode in your FileZilla (client) Connection's properties? That's often a cause of problems. (There's a great guide to understanding their differences [here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html)).

Remember:

- For Active connections open ports 20
  and 21
- For Passive connections open
  ports 21 and 1024+ (and higher)

I'll post more if I think of any further common problems. Good luck!

Comment: Don't forget to add your windows server firewall rules.