# FTP server, firewall, and showing the files in the ftp folder

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2008, port, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FileZilla not working on Server 2008 R2](https://superuser.com/questions/109938/filezilla-not-working-on-server-2008-r2)

I'm using ftp 7.5 on a windows 2008 server with basic authentication and a 5 digit port number for security reasons.

I can push files just fine, but it always fails to get back a list of files.  Filezilla errors saying it couldn't get the directory listing and if I ftp through windows explorer it times out.

So, I turned off the public profile in the windows firewall and it works fine.  Outbound connections are allowed by default.  The firewall logs are empty.

So, besides the port I specified in my FTP site, what else do I need to open up?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/109938/filezilla-not-working-on-server-2008-r2

Comment: The suggestions there did not fix my problem.